# SearchBar component borderRadius doesn't work

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I already tried using borderRadius properties on SearchBar component but it doesn't work

Already tried using borderWidth and borderRadius properties but still doesn't Work. Also i already tried using CSS border-radius but still doesn't Work. I am using Nativescript version 5.4.0

`<SearchBar hint="Insert Keyword" borderWidth="2" borderRadius="20" @submit="onSearchSubmit"/>`

and

`<SearchBar hint="Insert Keyword" borderTopWidth="2" borderTopLeftRadius="20" borderTopRightRadius="20" />`

Expected result is SearchBar with borderRadius is work

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen or some example code at the very least? Help others help you...

Comment: You are testing with Android or iOS?

Comment: please add a sandbox, or a code sample

Comment: sorry before, i already edit the post

Comment: I tried in many ways, even using clip path in CSS doesn't help. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=36fP8N

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/965

Comment: I would suggest open an issue in github repo https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Textfield instead and make it radiuses corners. Then add methods for search like this.

```
<TextField backgroundColor="white" paddingLeft="20" borderRadius="20" borderWith="3" class="input-search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" width="80%" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)" height="40" fontSize="14" hint="Search">
```